# AngularJS 1.5 two Controllers pass data via service

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.5.8
I got two controllers and can understand how does the other controllers locate the result of the first controllers.

**first controller**

On mouse down, I run a function that gathers some data for me in the service

```
$scope.mouseUpEvent = function () {

            customService.mycustom();
}
```

**Service**

```
app.service('customService', function(){
 this.mycustom = function(){
        var cvar = avar + bvar;
        return $scope.cvar;
    }
  }
```

**Other Controler***

```
$scope.gridCustom = customService.var;
```

How i can access cvar from my other controller ?

What want is for my first controller to call a function that calculates the content selected  than my second controller to read the selected content from my service and do custom content manipulations.

I've tried to set in the service a return method but still don't understand how to store the result in a method and setup the watch.

**Service**

```
app.service('customService', function(){
return{
       mycustom : function(){
           var cvar = avar + bvar;
           return $scope.cvar;
         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have a method on the service that returns it. And btw `$scope` shouldn't really be touched in services.

Comment: thank you for the heads up on scope, but how do I create a menthod? Gilles i have just started around services so don't know much.

Comment: Add a method to your service that returns the value which the first controller set on the service. The second controller should `$watch` the value returned and assign it to its scope.

Comment: Joseu, is there a way you post an answer on how to do this? I've tried experimenting creating a method and still no luck. I will update my question

Comment: No worries  guys, I figure it out. The angular vocabulary is a nightmare!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same way you access in controller1 using the method,

```
$scope.gridCustom = customService.mycustom();
```

Your service should be,

```
app.service('customService', function(){
 this.mycustom = function(){
        var cvar = avar + bvar;
        return cvar;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if I do that than it will run the function again. I just want the result of cvar.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs dude! it does not return the function, it returns the value of cvar.

Comment: yes I understand but it will run the algorithm in my function, I don't want that. I just want the car result that my controller had done for me.
Controller 2 should only take the output and use the ouput to manipulate the data

Answer (score 0):

A service you can think of as a box of database, it basically a database. You set the vairables via one controller and than use the other controller to fetch it. 
You can use watch , but watch is slow. It basically going every second and looking for changes.

In my case I should be storing a function in the service, I can store in the controller

Starting with controller 1:

```
$scope.mouseUpEvent = function () {
     //You called your function and stored in the service the result
     customService.result = $scope.mycustom();
}
// you function
$scope.mycustom = function(){
        var cvar = 4 + 6;
        return cvar;
}
```

Service

```
app.service('customService', function(){
    return{
        // you set you result to empty at first, and first controller will insert the result
         result : ''

     }
  });
```

**Controller 2**

```
//Now lets fetch the result

console.log(customService.result);
```

Don't forget that in each controller you need to specify you service. As angular relay on each service to work. Angular only collect the data/ service that you request.